# Select all with Squeryl scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, squeryl

I'm trying to select ALL of some table in a query. I have to specify a where clause (or so I tihnk), so what goes in there?

```
def all() = transaction { from(AppDB.users)(s => where(WHAT GOES HERE?) select(s)).toIndexedSeq }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it.

```
from(AppDB.users)(s => select(s))
```